# Splitting a Clojure namespace over multiple files

Tags: namespaces, clojure, compilation

Is it possible to split a Clojure namespace over multiple source files when doing ahead-of-time compilation with `:gen-class`? How do `(:main true)` and `(defn- ...)` come into play?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

### Overview

Certainly you can, in fact `clojure.core` namespace itself is split up this way and provides a good model which you can follow by looking in `src/clj/clojure`:

```
core.clj
core_deftype.clj
core_print.clj
core_proxy.clj
..etc..
```

All these files participate to build up the single `clojure.core` namespace.

### Primary File

One of these is the primary file, named to match the namespace name so that it will be found when someone mentions it in a `:use` or `:require`.  In this case the main file is `clojure/core.clj`, and it starts with an `ns` form.  This is where you should put *all* your namespace configuration, regardless of which of your other files may need them.  This normally includes `:gen-class` as well, so something like:

```
(ns my.lib.of.excellence
  (:use [clojure.java.io :as io :only [reader]])
  (:gen-class :main true))
```

Then at appropriate places in your primary file (most commonly all at the end) use `load` to bring in your helper files.  In `clojure.core` it looks like this:

```
(load "core_proxy")
(load "core_print")
(load "genclass")
(load "core_deftype")
(load "core/protocols")
(load "gvec")
```

Note that you don't need the current directory as a prefix, nor do you need the `.clj` suffix.

### Helper files

Each of the helper files should start by declaring which namespace they're helping, but should do so using the `in-ns` function.  So for the example namespace above, the helper files would all start with:

```
(in-ns 'my.lib.of.excellence)
```

That's all it takes.

### gen-class

Because all these files are building a single namespace, each function you define can be in any of the primary or helper files.  This of course means you can define your `gen-class` functions in any file you'd like:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  ...)
```

Note that Clojure's normal order-of-definition rules still apply for all functions, so you need to make sure that whatever file *defines* a function is loaded before you try to *use* that function.

### Private Vars

You also asked about the `(defn- foo ...)` form which defines a namespace-private function.  Functions defined like this as well as other `:private` vars are visible from within the namespace where they're defined, so the primary and all helper files will have access to private vars defined in any of the files loaded so far.

Comment: Very nice, complete answer! BTW, I'm almost finished on my first pass through _The Joy of Clojure_. Great book!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. Is it considered a good practice still, 2 years later? (I know things change fast.) I see that Clojure itself still uses this technique.

Comment: As of today this is still best practice if you are sure you want multiple files to generate a single namespace.  However, that itself may be less common now than it was.  An alternative may be to define all public vars of your ns in a single file, and move all helper vars and functions to a separate "implementation" namespace. The vars in impl would technically be public, but a ns docstring indicating they are not part of the documented API is common and should be sufficient.

Comment: Do we know if any common Clojure tooling has issues understanding multi-file namespaces? Lein? Boot? Cider? nREPL? Kibit? Eastwood? Cloverage? Etc...