# What does the idiomatic (defn -main ...) mean in a clojure program?

Tags: clojure

I'm familiar with packages from e.g. Java and Lisp, but what I'm seeing in other people's code is some apparent idioms like calling the entry point '-main' and using a backtick for the namespace name in (in-ns `foo), that kind of thing.  I don't see these spelled out anywhere in docs or tutorials.  Is there some resource which explains such conventions around structuring programs?

**Edit:**

I think I must have picked up the backtick thing from this answer: [Splitting a Clojure namespace over multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690758/splitting-a-clojure-namespace-over-multiple-files/4692067#4692067), which I stumbled across while trying to make sense of (defn -main ...).  Given the author, I took it as best practice.  However, now that I poke around in the Clojure sources he cites, I see that only the regular quote is used.  I guess most likely it's a typo.

(Narrowed the scope of the question title accordingly)

Comment: I've looked at a couple of similarly titled questions here, but they aren't what I'm looking for

Comment: the backtick in the in-ns is an interesting (and seemingly undocumented) trick. To clarify your question, do you mean the organization of definitions within a single source file or the organization of all the files in their package structure?

Comment: The latter definitely.  I *think* I saw the backtick thing in a post on this site. I'll try to track it down tomorrow. Need to sleep now.  zzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default for gen-class is to use - as the prefix for method names of that class. Which is why -main is the default entry point for java -cp clojure.jar yourclass

Backticks qualify their argument with the current namespace, so (in-ns `foo) is the same as (in-ns 'current-namespace/foo) and I don't think that's particularly idiomatic. The idiomatic way is to put each namespace in its own file with (ns ...) at the top, and use or require them as needed.

Comment: ok, I found gen-class, thank you +1.  As for the point about namespaces, I think I perhaps saw another structure with one source file defining (ns ...) and a bunch of others using (in-ns ...).

Comment: See link in my question for example of this style

Comment: @fizzer: yeah, I'm pretty certain that's a typo. And while splitting namespaces across files can be useful, I still wouldn't call it idiomatic.